# how to remove null spaces from tr output

Tags: bash

this is the output from `tr ',' '\n'`. when I tansform this in an array to use in a for loop, all the nulls are dropped and I need to have them there. I want to replace all the nulls with some value, i.e NULL and get from this list :

```
`
someApp
NA
All
`
All
value3
`
someVal
9999
`
```

to this :

```
NULL
someApp
NA
All
NULL
All
value3
NULL
someVal
9999
NULL
```

the ` doesn't exit. I added it just to mark empty values.

Comment: Please correct your terminology. A newline character is not an empty line, a NULL, or a space. It appears what you mean is *empty lines*. If those lines may or may not have spaces, you need to say that clearly. `\n` is an end-of-line marker character on *every* line, a null is a byte of all zeros, a space is a dedicated character that moves the print head but generates no other output. c.f. [this chart](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/1/1b/ASCII-Table-wide.svg)
Are you just trying to mark empty lines? Does that include lines with only spaces?

Answer (score 1):

You can drop `tr` and use `perl`:

```sh
perl -lne 'print join "\n", map {$_ ||= "NULL"} split(/,/, $_, -1)' file
```

Answer (score 0):

Would you please try the following:

```
str=",someApp,NA,All,,All,value3,,someVal,9999,"
echo "$str" | tr ',' '\n' | sed 's/^$/NULL/'
```

Output:

```
NULL
someApp
NA
All
NULL
All
value3
NULL
someVal
9999
NULL
```

The pattern `^$` to the sed `s` command matches an empty line and
is replaced with the string `NULL`.

Answer (score 0):

If you are just trying to mark empty lines, use

```
sed 's/^$/NULL/' file
```

If there can be spaces on those lines, and you still want them marked,

```
sed 's/^ *$/NULL/' file
```

Answer (score 0):

If `ed` is available/acceptable. No need for `tr`

```
printf '%s\n' $',s/,/\\\n/g' ',s/^$/NULL/' ,p Q | ed -s file
```